# Save Preferences in Fragment

Tags: java, android, checkbox, fragment, preferences

I have a fragment with 29 Checkboxes, and I want to save the preferences of those (if they're selected or not), so that when I reopen the app the checkboxes are selected or not (depending on the previous use)

I've implemented the sharedPreferences but it still won't save them. When I reopen the app (or when I change fragment and return), the checkboxes previously checked are unchecked (like reset).

I'm kind of new to android programming, so please excuse my noobyness.

This is my fragment.java

```
public class PresencasFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

CheckBox aula1;
(...)
CheckBox aula29;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_presencas, container, false);

    aula1 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aula1);
    (...)
    aula29 = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aula29);

    loadSavedPreferences();

    return rootView;
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    boolean aula1Val = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value1", false);
    (...)
    boolean aula29Val = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value29", false);

    if (aula1Val){
        aula1.setChecked(true);}
    else{
        aula1.setChecked(false);}

    (...)

    if (aula29Val){
        aula29.setChecked(true);}
    else{
        aula29.setChecked(false);}
}


private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(aula1.isChecked()) savePreferences("CheckBox_Value1",aula1.isChecked());

    (...)

    if(aula29.isChecked()) savePreferences("CheckBox_Value29",aula29.isChecked());
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you use a PreferenceFragment you save a *lot* of work

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have your own fragment for this, when you could be using the PreferenceFragment which was designed for this purpose? (or PreferenceActivity under API Level 11)

It does what you are doing automatically.

Check out this link for more info: http://android-er.blogspot.hu/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html

Comment: So, do I have to create all those .xml and .java files that are mentioned in the link? I have `PresencasFragment.java` and `fragment_presencas.xml` - do I have to create the `PrefsFragment.java` and `preferences.xml` or can I use my already created ones?

Comment: You need to create the R.xml.preferences (/res/xml/preferences.xml) and PreferenceFragment, sorry. However, luckily it will make the thing ever so much better and easier to handle.